# Programming Challenge: Python 3 DNS query resolver using socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, reinventing-the-wheel, socket

This is a DNS query resolver written in Python 3 using `socket`, I wrote it entirely by myself, it supports 8 primary DNS query types: A, NS, CNAME, SOA, PTR, MX, TXT, AAAA, and it is working correctly. Albeit the code is a little bit ugly.

Sample output:

```
In [22]: print(json.dumps(dns_query('deviantart.com', '8.8.8.8', 'SOA'), indent=4))
{
    "Question": {
        "ID": "0425",
        "Flags": {
            "Hexadecimal": "8180",
            "Binary": "1000000110000000",
            "Breakdown": {
                "Response": true,
                "Operation Code": "Query",
                "Authoritative Answer": false,
                "Truncated": false,
                "Recursion Desired": true,
                "Recursion Available": true,
                "Reserved": 0,
                "Authenticated Answer": false,
                "Non-authenticated Answer": "Unacceptable",
                "Error Code": "NoError"
            }
        },
        "Questions": 1,
        "Answers": 1,
        "Authorative Answers": 0,
        "Additional Resources": 0,
        "Name": "deviantart.com",
        "Type": "SOA",
        "Class": "INTERNET"
    },
    "Answers": [
        {
            "QName": "deviantart.com",
            "QType": "A",
            "QClass": "INTERNET",
            "Time-to-live": 232,
            "Data length": 4,
            "RData": "50.117.117.42"
        }
    ]
}

In [23]: print(json.dumps(dns_query('deviantart.com', '8.8.8.8', 'SOA'), indent=4))
{
    "Question": {
        "ID": "e52f",
        "Flags": {
            "Hexadecimal": "8180",
            "Binary": "1000000110000000",
            "Breakdown": {
                "Response": true,
                "Operation Code": "Query",
                "Authoritative Answer": false,
                "Truncated": false,
                "Recursion Desired": true,
                "Recursion Available": true,
                "Reserved": 0,
                "Authenticated Answer": false,
                "Non-authenticated Answer": "Unacceptable",
                "Error Code": "NoError"
            }
        },
        "Questions": 1,
        "Answers": 1,
        "Authorative Answers": 0,
        "Additional Resources": 0,
        "Name": "deviantart.com",
        "Type": "SOA",
        "Class": "INTERNET"
    },
    "Answers": [
        {
            "QName": "deviantart.com",
            "QType": "A",
            "QClass": "INTERNET",
            "Time-to-live": 176,
            "Data length": 4,
            "RData": "103.97.3.19"
        }
    ]
}

In [24]: print(json.dumps(dns_query('google.com', '8.8.8.8', 'SOA'), indent=4))
{
    "Question": {
        "ID": "3d0a",
        "Flags": {
            "Hexadecimal": "85b0",
            "Binary": "1000010110110000",
            "Breakdown": {
                "Response": true,
                "Operation Code": "Query",
                "Authoritative Answer": true,
                "Truncated": false,
                "Recursion Desired": true,
                "Recursion Available": true,
                "Reserved": 0,
                "Authenticated Answer": true,
                "Non-authenticated Answer": "Acceptable",
                "Error Code": "NoError"
            }
        },
        "Questions": 1,
        "Answers": 1,
        "Authorative Answers": 0,
        "Additional Resources": 0,
        "Name": "google.com",
        "Type": "SOA",
        "Class": "INTERNET"
    },
    "Answers": [
        {
            "QName": "google.com",
            "QType": "A",
            "QClass": "INTERNET",
            "Time-to-live": 60,
            "Data length": 4,
            "RData": "59.24.3.174"
        }
    ]
}

In [25]: print(json.dumps(dns_query('baidu.com', '8.8.8.8', 'SOA'), indent=4))
{
    "Question": {
        "ID": "9a50",
        "Flags": {
            "Hexadecimal": "8180",
            "Binary": "1000000110000000",
            "Breakdown": {
                "Response": true,
                "Operation Code": "Query",
                "Authoritative Answer": false,
                "Truncated": false,
                "Recursion Desired": true,
                "Recursion Available": true,
                "Reserved": 0,
                "Authenticated Answer": false,
                "Non-authenticated Answer": "Unacceptable",
                "Error Code": "NoError"
            }
        },
        "Questions": 1,
        "Answers": 1,
        "Authorative Answers": 0,
        "Additional Resources": 0,
        "Name": "baidu.com",
        "Type": "SOA",
        "Class": "INTERNET"
    },
    "Answers": [],
    "Authorative Answers": [
        {
            "QName": "baidu.com",
            "QType": "SOA",
            "QClass": "INTERNET",
            "Time-to-live": 7200,
            "Data length": 31,
            "RData": {
                "Primary Name Server": "dns.baidu.com",
                "Responsible Authority's Mailbox": "sa.baidu.com",
                "Serial Number": 2012145250,
                "Refresh Interval": 300,
                "Retry Interval": 300,
                "Expire Limit": 2592000,
                "Minimum TTL": 7200
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### ***Code***

```py
import ipaddress
import publicsuffix2 as psl
import random
import socket
import validators
from collections import defaultdict

QTYPE = {
    1: 'A',    
    2: 'NS',   
    5: 'CNAME',
    6: 'SOA',  
    12: 'PTR', 
    15: 'MX',  
    16: 'TXT', 
    28: 'AAAA',
    'A': 1,    
    'NS': 2,   
    'CNAME': 5,
    'SOA': 6,  
    'PTR': 12, 
    'MX': 15,  
    'TXT': 16, 
    'AAAA': 28
}

OPCODE = {
    0: 'Query',
    1: 'IQuery',
    2: 'Status',
    4: 'Notify',
    5: 'Update',
    6: 'DSO'
}

RCODE = {
    0: 'NoError',
    1: 'FormErr',
    2: 'ServFail',
    3: 'NXDomain',
    4: 'NotImp',
    5: 'Refused',
    6: 'YXDomain',
    7: 'YXRRSet',
    8: 'NXRRSet',
    9: 'NotAuth',
    10: 'NotZone',
    11: 'DSOTYPENI'
}

def byte2int(by: bytes) -> int:
    if not isinstance(by, bytes):
        raise TypeError()
    return int.from_bytes(by, 'big')

def byte2hex(by: bytes) -> str:
    if not isinstance(by, bytes):
        raise TypeError()
    return by.hex()

def dns_opcode(n: int):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError()
    if n not in OPCODE:
        raise ValueError()
    return OPCODE[n]

def dns_rcode(n: int):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError()
    if n not in RCODE:
        raise ValueError()
    return RCODE[n]

def dns_cd(n: int):
    if n not in (0, 1):
        raise ValueError()
    return ['Unacceptable', 'Acceptable'][n]

def dns_qclass(n: int):
    if n == 1:
        return 'INTERNET'
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid QCLASS value received')

DECODE_HEADER = [byte2hex, byte2hex, byte2int, byte2int, byte2int, byte2int]
FLAG_LENGTH = [1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
HEADERS = ['ID', 'Flags', 'Questions', 'Answers', 'Authorative Answers', 'Additional Resources']

FLAGS = [
    'Response',
    'Operation Code',
    'Authoritative Answer',
    'Truncated',
    'Recursion Desired',
    'Recursion Available',
    'Reserved',
    'Authenticated Answer',
    'Non-authenticated Answer',
    'Error Code'
]

SOA_NUMBERS = ['Serial Number', 'Refresh Interval', 'Retry Interval', 'Expire Limit', 'Minimum TTL']

DECODE_FLAG = [bool, dns_opcode, bool, bool, bool, bool, int, bool, dns_cd, dns_rcode]

def decode_flags(flag: str) -> dict:
    if not isinstance(flag, str):
        raise TypeError()
    if not (len(flag) == 4 and all(i in '0123456789abcdef' for i in flag)):
        raise ValueError()
    flag = '{:016b}'.format(int(flag, 16))
    index = 0
    flags = []
    for i, f in zip(FLAG_LENGTH, DECODE_FLAG):
        flags.append(f(int(flag[index:index+i], 2)))
        index += i
    return dict(zip(FLAGS, flags))

def decode_response(fields: bytes) -> dict:
    if not isinstance(fields, bytes):
        raise TypeError()
    if len(fields) != 10:
        raise ValueError()
    qtype = QTYPE[byte2int(fields[:2])]
    qclass = dns_qclass(byte2int(fields[2:4]))
    ttl = byte2int(fields[4:8])
    length = byte2int(fields[8:10])
    return {
        'QType': qtype,
        'QClass': qclass,
        'Time-to-live': ttl,
        'Data length': length
    }

def valid_domain(domain):
    return (validators.domain(domain) and psl.get_sld(domain, strict=True))

def make_query(query, qtype):
    if not (isinstance(query, str) and isinstance(qtype, str)):
        raise TypeError('Parameters must be instances of `str`')
    qtype = QTYPE.get(qtype.upper(), None)
    if not qtype:
        raise ValueError('QTYPE is invalid or unsupported')
    if qtype == 12:
        if validators.ipv4(query):
            query = ipaddress.IPv4Address(query).reverse_pointer
        elif validators.ipv6(query):
            query = ipaddress.IPv6Address(query).reverse_pointer
        else:
            raise ValueError('QUERY is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address')
    else:
        if not (validators.domain(query) and (sld := psl.get_sld(query, strict=True))):
            raise ValueError('QUERY is not a valid web domain')
        if qtype in (2, 15, 16):
            query = sld
    return b''.join([
        random.randbytes(2), b'\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0',
        ''.join(chr(len(i)) + i for i in query.split('.')).encode('utf8'),
        b'\0', qtype.to_bytes(2, 'big'), b'\0\1'
    ])

class DNS_Parser:
    def __init__(self, response: bytes) -> None:
        if not isinstance(response, bytes):
            raise TypeError('Argument must be an instance of `bytes`')
        self.response = response
        self.names = dict()
        self.question = dict()
        self.answers = []
        self.soa = []
        self.position = 0
        self.raw = dict()
        self.simple = dict()
    
    def check_bounds(self, pos: int):
        if not isinstance(pos, int):
            raise TypeError('Argument must be an instance of `int`')
        if pos >= len(self.response):
            raise IndexError('Index exceeds the maximum possible value')
    
    def read_stream(self, pos: int, recur: bool=False, length: int=0) -> str:
        self.check_bounds(pos)
        chunks = []
        count = 0
        while True:
            hint = self.response[pos]
            if hint == 0:
                if not recur:
                    self.position = pos
                break
            elif hint == 192:
                index = self.response[pos+1]
                self.position = pos+1
                if index in self.names:
                    name = self.names[index]
                else:
                    name = self.read_stream(index, True)
                    self.names[index] = name
                chunks.append(name)
                pos += 2
                count += 2
                if not length or count == length:
                    break
                else:
                    continue 
            pos += 1
            count += 1
            chunk = self.response[pos:pos+hint].decode('utf8')
            chunks.append(chunk)
            pos += hint
            count += hint
        return '.'.join(chunks)
    
    def parse_dns_query(self):
        pos = self.response[12:].index(0)
        query = self.response[:pos+17]
        headers = [f(query[:12][i:i+2]) for f, i in zip(DECODE_HEADER, range(0, 12, 2))]
        self.question = dict(zip(HEADERS, headers))
        flags = self.question['Flags']
        self.question['Flags'] = {
            'Hexadecimal': flags, 'Binary': f'{int(flags, 16):016b}',
            'Breakdown': decode_flags(flags)
        }
        name = self.read_stream(12)
        self.names[12] = name
        qtype = QTYPE[byte2int(query[pos+13:pos+15])]
        self.position = pos + 16
        self.question.update({
            'Name': name, 'Type': qtype,
            'Class': dns_qclass(byte2int(query[-2:]))
        })
    
    def rdata_ipv4(self, pos: int) -> str:
        self.check_bounds(pos+3)
        return '.'.join([str(i) for i in self.response[pos:pos+4]])
    
    def rdata_ipv6(self, pos: int) -> str:
        self.check_bounds(pos+15)
        return str(ipaddress.IPv6Address(self.response[pos:pos+16]))
    
    def rdata_txt(self, pos: int, length: int) -> dict:
        self.check_bounds(pos+length-1)
        return {'Text length': self.response[pos], 'Text': self.response[pos+1:pos+length+1].decode('utf8')}
    
    def rdata_mx(self, pos: int, length: int) -> dict:
        return {'Preference': byte2int(self.response[pos:pos+2]), 'Mail Exchange': self.read_stream(pos+2, length-2)}
    
    def rdata_soa(self, pos: int) -> dict:
        pns = self.read_stream(pos)
        ramx = self.read_stream(self.position+1)
        fields = self.response[self.position+1:self.position+21]
        soa = [byte2int(fields[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, 20, 4)]
        soa = dict(zip(SOA_NUMBERS, soa))
        rdata = {'Primary Name Server': pns, "Responsible Authority's Mailbox": ramx}
        rdata.update(soa)
        self.position += 20
        return rdata
    
    def parse_dns_answer(self):
        qname = self.read_stream(self.position+1)
        headers = decode_response(self.response[self.position+1:self.position+11])
        answer = {'QName': qname}
        answer.update(headers)
        qtype = headers['QType']
        length = headers['Data length']
        if length == 0:
            raise ValueError('DNS message is malformed or invalid')
        if qtype == 'A':
            if length != 4:
                raise ValueError('DNS message is malformed or invalid')
            rdata = self.rdata_ipv4(self.position+11)
            self.position += 14
        elif qtype == 'AAAA':
            if length != 16:
                raise ValueError('DNS message is malformed or invalid')
            rdata = self.rdata_ipv6(self.position+11)
            self.position += 26
        elif qtype == 'TXT':
            rdata = self.rdata_txt(self.position+11, length)
            if length - rdata['Text length'] != 1:
                raise ValueError('DNS message is malformed or invalid')
            self.position += (10 + length)
        elif qtype in ('CNAME', 'NS', 'PTR'):
            rdata = self.read_stream(self.position+11, length)
            if not valid_domain(rdata):
                raise ValueError('DNS message is malformed or invalid')
        elif qtype == 'MX':
            if length == 3 and self.response[self.position+13] == 0:
                prefs = byte2int(self.response[self.position+11:self.position+13])
                rdata = {'Preference': prefs, 'Mail Exchange': '<Root>'}
                self.position += 13
            else:
                rdata = self.rdata_mx(self.position+11, length)
                mx = rdata['Mail Exchange']
                if not valid_domain(mx):
                    raise ValueError('DNS message is malformed or invalid')
        elif qtype == 'SOA':
            rdata = self.rdata_soa(self.position+11)
            pns, ramx = rdata['Primary Name Server'], rdata["Responsible Authority's Mailbox"]
            if not (valid_domain(pns) and valid_domain(ramx)):
                raise ValueError('DNS message is malformed or invalid')
        answer['RData'] = rdata
        self.answers.append(answer) if qtype != 'SOA' else self.soa.append(answer)
    
    def parse_dns_response(self):
        self.parse_dns_query()
        total = sum((
            self.question['Answers'], 
            self.question['Authorative Answers'],
            self.question['Additional Resources']
        ))
        count = 0
        while count < total:
            self.parse_dns_answer()
            count += 1
        self.raw['Question'] = self.question
        self.raw['Answers'] = self.answers
        if self.soa:
            self.raw['Authorative Answers'] = self.soa

def dns_query(query, address, qtype):
    request = make_query(query, qtype)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.settimeout(2)
    try:
        sock.sendto(request, (address, 53))
        response = sock.recv(8192)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
    finally:
        sock.close()
    parser = DNS_Parser(response)
    parser.parse_dns_response()
    return parser.raw
```

It isn't complete yet, but it is indeed working properly and there are no bugs.

How can I improve its performance, refactor the code, improve readability, make it more structured, group the functions into classes, reduce code duplication and increase reuse rate, etc?

---

Well, I think I need to make something clear. Obviously this project wasn't done for practicality, I am not some sort of egomaniac arrogant enough to think my code is better than library code written by experienced professionals; This project was done in the name of learning only, it was a self-imposed challenge, I only did it to learn, in the hopes of improving my skills.

This script is poorly written and hacked together, but I really did learn a lot from the experience, I aimed for the process, not the result;

So if you don't like it and don't want to help me to improve, that's fine, just don't try to discourage me or say the script should be deleted.

---

Well I have found a bug in the code, but since there are answers I can't edit the code. The `length` parameter in `read_stream` is useless, remove that. There is no check against recursion after the pointer jumped back, so the position indicator (`self.position`) might be falsely decremented, thus breaking the code.

The solution is to put the indicator change inside `if not recur:` block.

---

Unfortunately fixing the previously mentioned bug introduces yet another bug, I have only encountered the bug just now.

Trying to query anything with `TXT` as `QTYPE` will raise the following:

```
In [164]: dns_query('example.com', '114.114.114.114', 'TXT').raw
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
...
<ipython-input-161-6d0c784748c1> in rdata_txt(self, pos, length)
    198
    199     def rdata_txt(self, pos: int, length: int) -> dict:
--> 200         return {'Length': self.response[pos], 'Text': self.response[pos+1:pos+length+1].decode('utf8')}
    201
    202     def rdata_mx(self, pos: int) -> dict:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

It can be fixed by simply removing `+1` after `length`. The error wasn't there before.

---

Anyways I have obtained something like this:

```
In [178]: print(json.dumps(multi_query('en.wikipedia.org', '8.8.8.8', 'SOA'), indent=4))
{
    "Question": {
        "Name": "en.wikipedia.org",
        "Type": "SOA",
        "Class": "INTERNET"
    },
    "Answers": {
        "A": [
            "202.160.128.210",
            "173.252.105.21"
        ],
        "CNAME": [
            "dyna.wikimedia.org"
        ]
    },
    "Authority": {
        "SOA": [
            {
                "MNAME": "ns0.wikimedia.org",
                "RNAME": "hostmaster.wikimedia.org",
                "Serial": 2022031717
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It combines information from multiple responses to one single query into a single dictionary:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't repeat yourself

You currently store the reverse mappings explicitly in `QTYPE`:

```py
QTYPE = {
    1: 'A',    
    2: 'NS',   
    5: 'CNAME',
    6: 'SOA',  
    12: 'PTR', 
    15: 'MX',  
    16: 'TXT', 
    28: 'AAAA',
    'A': 1,    
    'NS': 2,   
    'CNAME': 5,
    'SOA': 6,  
    'PTR': 12, 
    'MX': 15,  
    'TXT': 16, 
    'AAAA': 28
}
```

Maybe just do it once and add then reverse dict programmatically:

```py
QTYPE = {
    1: 'A',    
    2: 'NS',   
    5: 'CNAME',
    6: 'SOA',  
    12: 'PTR', 
    15: 'MX',  
    16: 'TXT', 
    28: 'AAAA'
}
QTYPE = {**QTYPE, **{value: key for key, value in QTYPE.items()}}
```

### Runtime type checks

Remove runtime type checks and with them the useless conversion functions.
Python is a dynamically typed language. The parser will complain if an object does not support a certain method via an `AttributeError`. Also they are unnecessarily costly.

### Don't micromanage types (again)

Consider:

```py
def dns_opcode(n: int):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError()
    if n not in OPCODE:
        raise ValueError()
    return OPCODE[n]
```

vs.

```py
def dns_opcode(n: int):
    return OPCODE[n]  # Will throw a KeyError on invalid opcodes
```

And with this the function becomes virtually useless, since you can call `OPCODE[n]` at the given time directly.

### Avoid magic numbers

I have no idea what `b'\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0'` is. Put it into a global variable with a descriptive name.

### Divide and conquer

Some functions are currently pretty long. Especially `read_stream()` and `parse_dns_answer()`. Consider splitting them into smaller functions dealing with a part of the problem. Since the latter has a long if/else block, it should be a good candidate to split the parser into functions for each response type.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your only concern, delete this project and use the operating system's resolver as presented through the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) library. Have you compared the performance of your resolver with that of the operating system?

If this code "needs to exist" (perhaps for learning purposes), it's crucial to understand that this process is I/O-bound, and the vast majority of execution time will be spent waiting on the network. This will become apparent if you profile, there being no evidence that you've done so. As such, the only significant thing that you can do to improve performance is cache, which it seems you aren't doing.